# Can i add special characters in wordpress permalinks like "&", "?", "=", "_"?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am now workin at a website http://telefoane.com.ro/star-promotion and the old one is http://star-promotion.ro . I want to keep the permalinks as they are because the website is indexed in google with a good position. Is there a plugin that can make it? Basic plugins just changes the "&" or "?" in smth like "F3"..

Comment: You can not use special characters like these in permalinks. You will have create permalinks without those character and put an redirect for old url to new corresponding url.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use,

**Redirection plugin:** http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ with Regex in your theme.

You can get the solution.